# How do I connect an AWS RDS instance and Datagrip?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datagrip

I have created a AWS RDS database instance and I am trying to connect it to Datagrip. I chose Easy create, MySQL, Freetier and set the name as audiotranscribe. The profile of the instance is as follows:

[image]

In Datagrip I selected MySQL as the data source, used the password and username I set the instance up with, and set the hostname as the endpoint:

[image]

However, I'm getting the error:

[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up. java.net.UnknownHostException:

Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The instance is not publicly accessible, so you will not be able to connect to it from the Internet. You will need to either make it publicly accessible (not a good idea) or connect to it through a VPN.